# Why C# Task.Run() method print the same number in the loop in console app?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have created a **console app** which print the number in a for loop using `C# Task.Run()` method. If you look at the code, I am initializing the `Employee object` in the loop and pass the number in the method, though it prints the same number.

**Code:**

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
            {
                Task.Run(() => new Employee().ProcessEmployee(i));
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public void ProcessEmployee(int employeeId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The number is: {employeeId} and thread is {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**The question is**- How would I fix this issue? I still want to use `Task.Run()` method because in my real application scenarios, I want to process the stream (JSON data) in a different thread and do not want to block my main callback method which receive the stream (JSON data).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Task.Run with Parameter(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225476/task-run-with-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the task actually starts, the value of `i` has already incremented.

try assigning value of `i` to another variable and then pass that variable.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++)
        {
            int j = i;
            Task.Run(() => new Employee().ProcessEmployee(j));
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public void ProcessEmployee(int employeeId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"The number is: {employeeId} and thread is {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    }
}
```

Edit: duplicate/source : [For Loop result in Overflow with Task.Run or Task.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275831/for-loop-result-in-overflow-with-task-run-or-task-start)

Answer (score 1):

This is because lambda capture variables, so they all refer to `i`, and by the time your task runs the for `i` is already at 501. You need to store a local variable within your for and copy the current value of `i` and use that in your lambda so that this specific variable (that is declared within the scope of the loop and thus a new variable each iteration) is the one that is captured

```
for(int i = ....)
{
    var tmp = i;
    Task.Run(() => new Employee().ProcessEmployee(tmp));
}
```